# Load SOAP response while it is in process PHP

Tags: php, soap

Has someone any idea if I can output a PHP SOAP response while the request is in process, I tried severel things but no results, it seems to be not possible, is that possible at all?

So my thing is, how do I output the result of a SOAP request while SOAP is still in process?

Comment: How can server response on request that has not been made yet? Maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: After I made the request and the request is still in process, I want to output results which the server sent back already, but the server is still in proccess to send more results.

Comment: It depends which language you use in client-side. Anyway you need to output response asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can read `results which the server sent back already` for a soap response. The soap response comes in an envelope, analogous to a real postal letter. Both comes as a single message, and once delivered, you can open and read it. There is no way to can read the first page of a postal letter while "the rest is still arriving"..

On the other hand, if you are calling multiple Soap services, then you can do that asynchronously and show each soap response as soon as that particular soap response envelope has completed delivery. This is just like regular asynchronous ajax processing, and there is nothing additional to it.

Comment: I understand, but is there a way to check how many percent the server has respond (i.e. 1%, 2%)?

Comment: None, AFAIK..additionally remember that since soap responses are XML formatted, any partial processing is an invalid XML, and in turn, an invalid response.

Comment: Thank you Raidenace, thought I need to let my customer wait until the server responded back :)